# What does the number beside the icon represent?

Tags: tampermonkey

What does the number mean in read and why does it increment from 1 to 2? It looks similar to firebugs error count, but there are no errors here.

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The badge will show different information depending on your settings.

To see the current behavior (and change it):

1. Go to Tampermonkey settings
2. Make sure `Config Mode` is set to `Beginner` or `Advanced` as you will not be able to change the setting when in `Novice` mode
3. Find `Icon Badge Info` on the settings screen and set it to your liking.

In Novice mode this is showing the number of "running script instanced". E.g. if you're on a page where you have a script running and that page also has an iframe with the script running the badge will say 2.